# Any with singular countable nouns in questions

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement, countable-nouns

As far as I know, a countable noun should be plural after *any* in questions. For example:

> Are there any books on the desk?

So is it incorrect to say:

> Is there any means of contacting him?

([Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/means?q=means))

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112996/any-followed-by-singular-or-plural-countable-nouns

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford Dictionaries `'mean'` can be **`"treated as singular or plural"`**.

**Means (noun)**:
Even though it ends in an ‘s’, means is a singular noun. We use a singular verb with it. We use it to talk about a method of doing something:

> The most economical means of travelling to Aberdeen is by plane.

Check [this.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/mean)

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, a countable noun should be plural after any in
>   questions.

That's not right. As to your question, both singular and plural nouns can be used after the word *any*.
E.g.,
*Is there any chance of going to cinema?

Are there any historical books in the library?

She doesn't have any friends.*

> So is it incorrect to say:
>   Is there any means of contacting him?

No, it is correct. Here the word "*means*" means *method*, *way*, *medium* etc.
So your sentence can be paraphrased this way:

*Is there any way/method of contacting him?*

Comment: Indeed, "any" can be used with both singular and plural nouns, but it's meaning would change. "Chance" in your example is uncountable. As for "any way/method", I'd use the cardinal article "a" here: "is there a way/method"